# How to set up Internet Connection Sharing (ICS) in Windows 10 with a static IP device?

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, internet

I have a device with a static IP address (102.168.200.10) which is connected to a windows 10 computer through an adaptor with IP 192.168.200.5. The computer itself is connected to the internet via WLAN.

I want to set up Internet Connection Sharing (ICS) for that device. To do so I follow instructions like [THIS](https://www.monnit.com/support/knowledgebase/gateways/sharing-your-windows-10-pc-internet-connection-with-an-ethernet-gateway/). However, in the instructions it also says that

```
The connecting device must be set to receive an IP address via DHCP
```

But this device cannot receive an IP via DHCP.

Is there still a way to enable internet sharing, so that on the device itself I can do

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

for example, i.e. the device reaches the internet through the WLAN on windows 10?

P.S. I am able to change the IP address of the device manually to any value ...

Comment: DHCP isn’t required just the assignment of an IP address that has a route to the device that is implementing ICs

Comment: And how do I do that?

Comment: Since you don't know how to do that, don't try to put it in another subnet, and assign it a static ip address in the `192.168.200.x` subnet

Comment: What do you mean by "assign 'it' a static ip address". What do you mean by 'it'? The device? The adaptpr? Both have static I addresses in the `192.168.200.x` subnet ...